# How to make a start in converting the worksheet to a list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the worksheet like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | MARY | PETER | SAM |
| APPLE | 1 | 1 |  |
| BANANA |  |  |  |
| PLUM | 1 |  | 1 |

And I want to convert to be this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| APPLE | MARY |
| APPLE | PETER |
| PLUM | MARY |
| PLUM | SAM |

I am using office 365 and tried the

```
=FILTER(A2:D5,B2:B5=1)
```

formula, but it is not what I expected.

Which fix can be more efficient and easier to apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> & <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=HSTACK(
        TOCOL(REPT(A2:A4,IF(B2:D4<>1,NA(),1)),3),
        TOCOL(REPT(B1:D1,IF(B2:D4<>1,NA(),1)),3)
        )
```

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=HSTACK(
        TOCOL(IF(B2:D4="",NA(),A2:A4),3),
        TOCOL(IF(B2:D4="",NA(),B1:D1),3)
        )
```

---

Or, break it down into parts using <kbd>LET( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,IF(B2:D4="",NA(),1),
     b,TOCOL(REPT(A2:A4,a),3),
     c,TOCOL(REPT(B1:D1,a),3),
     HSTACK(b,c)
     )
```

---

Below screenshot is an example, not necessarily has to be `1` in cells `B2:D4`

[image]

---

Or, Taking the whole data and **dissecting** it.

```
=LET(
     _data,A1:D4,
     _name,DROP(INDEX(_data,1,),,1),
     _fruits,DROP(INDEX(_data,,1),1),
     _body,DROP(_data,1,1),
     _errorCheck,IF(_body<>"",1,NA()),
     _unfruits,TOCOL(REPT(_fruits,_errorCheck),3),
     _unname,TOCOL(REPT(_name,_errorCheck),3),
     HSTACK(_unfruits,_unname))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Here another way of applying `HSTACK/TOCOl`:

```
=LET(A,A2:A4,in,B2:D4,h,B1:D1,
  HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(in<>"",A,NA()),2),TOCOL(IF(in<>"",h,NA()),2)))
```

[image: output]

The first `IF` searches for non empty values by columns and the second `IF` does it by rows. Then it uses `TOCOL` removing `NA()` values (`2` second input argument). Finally, stack the each result horizontally via `HSTACK`.